# Is there any Doxygen document hosting service for CI based opensource github projects?

Tags: documentation, continuous-integration, doxygen

I have a prject that uses travis-ci and coveralls and fresh view on stats is quite usefull for us. I wonder if there is any coveralls like service for documentation hosting?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at **[Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/)**: Hosted documentation generator, integrates with [VCS systems](http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vcs.html). There is a third-party extension to [integrate Doxygen](http://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).